Is there any solution $u\left(t,x\right)$ that satisfies the following system of equations?
Is there any solution $u\left(t,x\right)$ that satisfies the following equation (sorry for the “oddly specific formula”)?
$$\begin{cases}
\vartheta\left(\mu-x\right)=\frac{a}{b}\sigma-\frac{\sigma}{b}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\left(t,x\right)\\
\sigma=\frac{1}{b}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\left(t,x\right)
\end{cases},$$
where $\sigma,\vartheta>0$, $a,b,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$.
I'm a “starter” in these kind of equations, but I'm not sure there exists any solution, because $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\left(t,x\right)=\sigma b\Longrightarrow u\left(t,x\right)=\int\sigma bdx+c_{1}\left(t\right)=\sigma bx+c_{1}\left(t\right)$$
and
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\left(t,x\right)=-\frac{b}{\sigma}\vartheta\left(\mu-x\right)+a\Longrightarrow u\left(t,x\right)=\int\left(-\frac{b}{\sigma}\vartheta\left(\mu-x\right)+a\right)dt=-\frac{b}{\sigma}\vartheta\left(\mu-x\right)t+at+c_{2}\left(x\right),$$
where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are continuous functions.
However, I'm not sure we can find $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ where the following equation is true for all $t,x$ pairs
$$\sigma bx+c_{1}\left(t\right)=-\frac{b}{\sigma}\vartheta\left(\mu-x\right)t+at+c_{2}\left(x\right)$$
because of the cross term “$xt$”.  Is that correct?

$\sigma,\vartheta$ are constants or functions?

To ease on things, let them be constants. (Initially I was thinking on constants.)

$b$ has to be $\neq 0$?

Yes, I think for $b=0$ it would be easy.

You already know that both are necessary differentiable, derive wrt Xand t
.you will probably have a contradiction.

Write it as $\nabla u = \omega$ with $\omega(t,x) := (a-\frac{b}{\sigma} \vartheta (\mu - x), b\sigma)$ with $(t,x ) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. It has a solution if and only if
$$\frac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \omega_2}{\partial t}$$
It is
$$\frac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial x}(t,x) = \frac{b}{\sigma} \vartheta \, \text{ and } \,\frac{\partial \omega_2}{\partial t}(t,x) = 0 $$
Therefore there is a solution if and only if $ \vartheta = 0$ or $b = 0$.
As $b \neq 0$ and $\vartheta > 0$ there is no solution.

Thanks. It makes sense.
